# Keybinding for forward-page and backward-page

Tags: key-bindings, motion, page

Have been trying to make a keybinding for `forward-page` and `backward-page` with

```
(global-set-key (kbd "H-]") (forward-page))
(global-set-key (kbd "H-[") (backward-page))
```

But these give

```
H-] is undefined
H-[ is undefined
```

What is happening?  What would be a fix for it?

Comment: Is `H` defined as a prefix key? See the Elisp manual for how to do that. (You know that `C-x ]` and `C-x [` are already bound for this, right?)

Comment: I have been using the `H-` binding, so at a loss how  `H-]`  and  `H-]` are being reported as undefined.  I know about the  `C-x ]`  and  the  `C-x [`  binding, but would like a more rapid binding.

Comment: @Drew, I think he means to use the `Hyper` key which is a modifier, so it does not need to be defined as a prefix key - right? OTOH, I have never understood how to define a `Hyper` key, if one is not using a special keyboard - in X11, one could use `xmodmap` theoretically, but I don't have a reliable recipe.

Comment: Correct.  I am using the `Hyper Key` as modifier using  `xmodmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs (`C-h f global-set-key`):

> global-set-key is an interactive native compiled Lisp function in
> ‘subr.el’.
>
> (global-set-key KEY COMMAND)
>
> Give KEY a global binding as COMMAND.
> COMMAND is the command definition to use; usually it is
> a symbol naming an interactively-callable function.

The last bit means that we must do this:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "H-]") 'forward-page)
(global-set-key (kbd "H-[") 'backward-page)
```